# How to make a file writable with IIS7?

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, php5

I am using IIS7 on my local PC for PHP development. I have problem creating a writable file inside my document root where PHP would be allowed to write logs to.

I get this error:

```
Specified file is not writeable
```

How can I set a file to be writable by PHP? I tried right clicking the file and the Read-only checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the correct NTFS permissions to the file or folder where you want to write the file.

In many cases (Where your site is configured for anonymous access this will be the IUSR account, if you have custom settings you will need to figure out which account is providing the anonymous access.

The NTFS permissions you give depend on what you're planning to do, a good guide on NTFS Permissions is: http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Understanding-Windows-NTFS-Permissions.html